# How to customise Content Query Webpart to get this view

Tags: content-query-web-part

I would like to customise the Content Query Webpart  like i normally do with DWP but i 
know its a different approach.

All i want to do is to get the title name and turn it into a link and when you click the title link i want it come up with a a custom page that i would create and pass some querystring parameters to it.

Something like this

e.g

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('/sites/Sample/Pages/GMComms.aspx?ID={@ID}','{$title}'); return true "><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>
```

the openDialog is the

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog();
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you'll have to either modify or create a new XSLT Template in the ItemStyle.xsl file, which you find in the `/Style Library/XSLT Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl`

In the template you can insert javascript as follow:

```
<script language="javascript" defer="true">
  <xsl:comment>
    <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready( function() {
        // logic here

        // Example to include XSLT variables
        $('#AnchorID').click(function () {
          var url = $(this).attr('href');
          SP.UI.ModalDialog.openModalDialog(url,]]> <xsl:value-of select="$title"/> <![CDATA[);
        });
      });
    ]]>
  </xsl:comment>
</script>
```